# Pass number as a column name in select statement of Sql

Tags: mysql

My query is like this

```
select 5 from mytable_name;
```

Then the output is like column name 5 and the value is 5 printing as many max number of rows exists in that table.
Can anybody tell the reason why this query is working like this?

Answer (score 6):

> Can anybody tell the reason why this query is working like this?

You are selecting a string literal value `'5'` for each row in your table:

```
select 5 from mytable_name;
```

And this works fine. Because in the `SELECT` statement you can select:

- Column reference,
- Literal value like in your case.
- Function.
- value expression.
- Select expression.

As defined by the standard SQL<sup>**1**</sup>:

[image]

**Update:**

However, If you have a column with a name is a number like in your case, you have to escape it in order to select the values in it like so:

```
 SELECT `143` FROM Table1;
```

This will select all the rows in the column `143`.

But, this:

```
 SELECT 143 FROM Table1;
```

Will select the string literal 143 for each row found in the table.

**Note that:** If possible, try not to name these columns this way, it is recommended and a best practice, not to do this.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60de8/1)

---

### **Update 2:**

Note that, if you select `143` or `'143'`, or even `"143"` this will select the literal value `143` not the column date. The following are the same:

```
SELECT 143 FROM Table1;
SELECT '143' FROM Table1;
SELECT "143" FROM Table1;
```

All these `SELECT`s won't select the data in the column, They will select the literal value `143` not the column data. See this demo:

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60de8/6)

You have to escape the column name with the two:

```
``
```

Like this:

```
SELECT `143` FROM table1;
```

Not:

```
SELECT '143' FROM table1'
```

Like what I did here:

### [The right Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60de8/7)

---

<sup>1<sup>Image From: [**SQL Queries for Mere Mortals**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201433362)</sup></sup>

Comment: Very thanks for reply. As you told let us say it is allowing value expressions what you said. Assume I have created a column name called 143. I have inserted some values for that column. Now execute the query like "select 143 from table_name". It is not giving values what I have inserted, it is creating new column here. Now  so my doubts is how it is able to create new column for external strings or numbers even that column exists in table.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud Gamal, The output what you said is wrong(I have tried). Both queries "select 143 from table_name; and select '143' from table_name;" will give same output. And Yes, I know -:), creating a column like this is not meaningful. But have enthusiasm to find the reason for this behavior of the query.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal thank you, its working fine with `and`. But when you pass a literal value why it is considering as a new column name instead of throwing error. Is there any special reason behind this?

Comment: @sankar - There is no special reason behind that. This was already permitted by the SQL Standard, this is why I posted the diagram in my answer. Why it doesn't throw an error, because it is permitted. Thats it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got clarity with good explanation from you. But till I'm wondering why DB allowing this type of expressions without a reason. It looks very funny...:). Once again thank you for every reply of you.

Answer (score 1):

```
from mytable
```

will select all rows from your table if there is no `where` condition that shrinks that result. and

```
select 5
```

will select the constant number `5` for every record. If you use a column name in the `select` part then that value will be selected for every record.

The DB engine will name the result `5` because it automatically generates a column name and 5 is the logical name for that.

Comment: First let me say thank you for your reply. Ya, The DB engine creating new column with the number or string we are passing. Actually the syntax of select statement is "SELECT [COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME,....] FROM TABLE_NAME". But here we are not passing any column name of the table. To say fact its has throw error because column name is not exists. so my doubts is how it is able to create new column for external strings or numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You want 'SELECT * FROM mytable_name LIMIT 0,5' perhaps?

Comment: +1, somehow I suspect this is what he wanted to do even though the question doesn't actually say it.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje My question doesn't mean that. You can see my conversation with Mahmoud Gamal, Then you can understand my doubt about this kind of behavior from query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have anything in your where clause, it is selecting all the rows from your table.  The fact that you don't select any of the columns is irrelevant - you'll still get a result for each row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

With the command `select 5 ...` you are viewing a fixed value. Same thing you run the following command: `select "test"`, you will be displaying a fixed string.
Using `... from mytable_name` you're looking for all record of this table.

With this we can conclude that for each record in the table `mytable_name` shows you the fixed value `"5"`.

Comment: What is the reason for this ambiguity??? Please see my reply to @Mahmoud Gamal answer. If possible give exact reason for this behavior of query.